# Where am I supposed to call the method connection.Open() using C#?

Tags: c#, database, datareader

Hi I am trying to get data from a database shown in a textbox. Doing this I have created three classes: Dal, Controller and TestForm. The thing is that I dont really know where to open the connection nor where to close it. This is what I've done.

In the class Dal I have:

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.Odbc;

    namespace TestingDatabaseConnection
    {
        class Dal
        {
    private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

        public SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {

            if (connection == null)
            {
               connection.ConnectionString = "Server=Mnemonics-DAT;Database=mem;    Integrated Security = true;";
            }

            return connection;
        }

     public SqlDataReader GetData() 
        {
            SqlDataReader sqlReads = null;

                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table_name", GetConnection());
                 sqlReads = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            return sqlReads;


        }
    }
    }
```

In the class Controller I have:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TestingDatabaseConnection
    {
    class Controller
    {
        private Dal dal = new Dal();

        public SqlDataReader GetData()
        {
            return dal.GetData();
        }
    }
    }
```

and finally in the form:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
Controller controll; 

public TestForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    controll = new Controller();
}

private void showBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = controll.GetData();
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            infTxtBox.Text = sqlReader.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something is wrong: " + e1);
    }

}

}
```

The message I get says "Something is wrong: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

---

What I have tried to do to solve the problem(in the class Dal):

Making a property that gets the connection value like this:

```
public SqlConnection Connect
    {
        get
        {
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

And then using it in the method GetData():

```
 public SqlDataReader GetData() 
        {
            SqlDataReader sqlReads = null;
            try
            {
                 //I call the method Open() here
                Connect.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table_name", GetConnection());
                sqlReads = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error is: " + e);
            }
            finally
            {
                //and close it here
                Connect.Close();
            }
            return sqlReads;


        }
```

The error message I get now says: "Something is wrong: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed"
While referring to the class TestForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
if (connection == null)
{
     connection.ConnectionString = "Server=Mnemonics-DAT;Database=mem;    Integrated Security = true;";
}
```

Your connection can't be null because you initializing it before calling `GetConnection` method.Instead check your connection string:

```
if(connection.ConnectionString == "")
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=Mnemonics-DAT;Database=mem;    Integrated Security = true;";
}
```

Probably it would better if you use [`using statements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx),it will automatically `Dispose` your `Connection` object when it's job is done, just define a connection string variable then use:

```
string connString = "Server=Mnemonics-DAT;Database=mem; Integrated Security = true";

using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table_name", conn))
{
      conn.Open();
      sqlReads = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
      conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Selman22, thanks for your help but I get the same error message. Did update to connection.ConnectionString == "" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mnemonics it should be `connection.ConnectionString == ""` not `connection.ConnectionString == null`  I changed

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** in `Dal` class file you are not opening your connection object `connection` before reading the data.

**Solution :** You need to Open the `SqlConnection` object using `Open()` method before reading the data.

Try This:

```
    public SqlDataReader GetData() 
    {
        SqlDataReader sqlReads = null;
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table_name", GetConnection());
        connection.Open(); //Open your connection object here.
        sqlReads = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        return sqlReads;
    }
```

Comment: Ohh I thought I had tried this but I was wrong. Thank you for the correct answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @Mnemonics: You are welcome :) Glad tobe help of you.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi actually he is calling Open method but he didn't set connection string because that if statement always become **false** (inside of  `GetConnection` method)

Comment: @Selman22: yes dear, i just noticed that at the end but in first `DAL`  class it was not Opened , thatwhat pointed, Thanks Dear for your valuable point.

Comment: I would like some critique of my post. Is the question valid or should I be more specific? Is it too much code or is it "enough" for you to go through it and maybe find the solution? What should I think next time I ask a question?

Comment: @Mnemonics: i think everybody does this initially. what we expect is clear explanation with relavent code :) , All The Best...

Comment: @Mnemonics: i also suggest you to accept `selman22` answer because it has relavent information with best practices like usage of `using{}` blocks.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I think I can only accept one answer. And I can't vote up his answer becuase I have too low reputation. But it will get voted up when I get more reputation. Maybe I should give him the accepted answer? You decide :p

Comment: @Mnemonics: Yes you can only Accept one Answer :) , Accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're trying to read your SqlDataReader on a closed connection.

Do not call connection.close() in your getData() method instead add a method to your Dal class 
like so :

```
public void CloseConnection()
{
    connect.close()
}
```

and then call your closeConnection method after looping trough your DataReader :

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader = controll.GetData();
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            infTxtBox.Text = sqlReader.ToString();
        }

control.CloseConnection();
```